# How do you handle async initialization of an object?

Tags: java, dart, oop, design-patterns, architecture

Let's say I have an object `Foo` which requires some asynchronous work, `bar()`, to be done before it is ready to be used. It feels like each solution I try, I run into an anti-pattern.

Solutions considered:

- Keep an `initialized` variable in `Foo`. Call `bar()` in Foo's constructor. When `bar()` completes, set `initialized = true`. My issue with this approach is that it introduces uninitialized and initialized states into the object, which in my understanding should be avoided.
- Setup `Foo` in a parent and inject the data in via arguments. My problem with this approach is that it just pushes the issue farther up the stack; if this is done, now some other class is responsible for doing `Foo`'s initial work.

What is common practice in a situation like this? Thanks!

Comment: Why does `Foo` need to be constructed before `bar()` is done?

Comment: @shmosel My specific use case is the creation of a persistent file cache. It needs to do some initial work - loading previously cached files from storage into memory, and setting up/retrieving a cache log for metadata. I feel like these should be responsibilities of the `FileCache` itself, to avoid implementation complexity for the user of the `FileCache`.

Comment: Have you looked at `Future`? Edit: 30s too slow. The answer below has an example using `Future`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a static factory method that returns a Future?

```
class Foo {
    private static final ExecutorService executor =
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    
    public static Future<Foo> construct() {
        return executor.submit(() -> {
            bar();
            return new Foo();
        });
    }

    private Foo() {}
}
```